# Compare differences with package default configuration files

Tags: package-management

So I just did a package upgrade on a server and was asked, as I have been many hundreds of times before the following question:

```
Configuration file `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** fastcgi_params (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

Muscle memory took over, I hit return and the default of N (keep your installed version) happened.

However, I would actually quite like to see the differences between my version and the maintained copy. There may be some improvements, there might not be. It's hard to know after the fact.

Now I know I could download a copy of the package, or rummage through my cache and find it there but is there a quicker way? Is there a way, for example, that I could run through the configuration files to be asked the question all over again?

Note: I don't neccessarily want to overwrite my copy - I just want to compare it to a new, fresh copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maintainer's version of the file should be there with the same name but an added extension `.dpkg-dist`.

So in your case `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params.dpkg-dist` should be the maintainer's version of your `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`.

By extension, you can compare the two with a quick diff:

```
$ diff /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params{,.dpkg-dist}
5a6
> fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
21c22
< fastcgi_param HTTPS           $https;
---
> fastcgi_param HTTPS           $https if_not_empty;
```